# On opening a .js file, auto completion is working but an error message is showing on startup

Tags: plugin-coc

When I'm opening my app.js file in the vim status bar following error is shown

```
[coc.nvim] Failed to load the ESLint library for the document /mnt/d/js/my_take/js_sandbox/app.js
```

Even though the autocompletion is working, I'm curious to know why this is happening.

Comment: See https://github.com/neoclide/coc-eslint/issues/11 there are suggestions there to fix this, one of them might work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Tae](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25532/22375) pointed, that's not really about vim, nor CoC.

This message is displayed (most probably) because you have no `.eslint` nor `.eslint.json`, which are  needed for CoC to use the linter.

First, you'll need `eslint` if it's not already installed:

```
npm i -g eslint
```

You can then generate these files with the config demon. Run this command from your project root:

```
eslint --init
```

Follow the instructions and pick options depending on your project.
You can also refer to the [eslint user guide](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface).

Edit:

You'll also need some config in your `coc-settings.json` file (which you can open with `:CocConfig`):

```
"eslint.filetypes": [
    "javascript",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact",
    "javascriptreact"
],
"eslint.options" : {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this brief answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't use CoC, but [ESLint](https://eslint.org) is an static analyzer and has nothing to do with code completion, that's why it is working.

As far as I know CoC provides more than code completion, and if ESLint is not being loaded you may be missing its diagnostics